# Ruby: What does binds mean in ActiveRecord gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I saw binds as argument in lots of methods, but without any documentation.

e.g. [Rails Source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/055493ce056a663a7b61ae4f88f657d1a355995d/activerecord/lib/active_record/querying.rb#L40)

```
def find_by_sql(sql, binds = [], preparable: nil, &block)
  result_set = connection.select_all(sanitize_sql(sql), "#{name} Load", binds, preparable: preparable)
  column_types = result_set.column_types.dup
  columns_hash.each_key { |k| column_types.delete k }
  message_bus = ActiveSupport::Notifications.instrumenter

  payload = {
    record_count: result_set.length,
    class_name: name
  }

  message_bus.instrument("instantiation.active_record", payload) do
    result_set.map { |record| instantiate(record, column_types, &block) }
  end
end
```

1. what does `binds` mean?
2. How to use it?

Comment: you can use named bind variables to make query easier to read. Named bind variables replace the question marks with symbols and you supply a hash with values for the matching symbol key . please check this article http://millarian.com/rails/quick-tip-rails-named-bind-variables/

Answer (score 1):

When your SQL contain question marks `?` the binds are used to replace these marks. For example if you have a query like this: `SELECT * from posts where id = 3` you can write in Ruby:

`Post.find_by_sql(["SELECT * from posts where id = ?", 3])`

We have binded the `?` with the value `3`.
If we have more `?` they will be binded with the binds array in that order.
If there are not `?` in the SQL string binds are ignored.